# How to stop Playback command when a digit is detected?

Tags: asterisk

When I play a file using Playback command in Asterisk, it doesn't stop playing when a key is pressed on the phone. Is there a way to stop playing and go to the next command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playback is not intended to read input from the user, but as a kind of tool for playing a welcome message (note that Playback will answer the channel if not answered). The [manual for Playback](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Playback) does not say anything about reading input from the user. Furthermore, this [voip-info](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Playback) page states:

```
Playback will play the whole sound file(s), and when complete, return control.
```

So try using [Read](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_Read) in your dialplan, like:

```
Read(get,"mysound", 1)
```

This will play the sound **mysound**, and read up to 1 digit from the user. More examples (and the complete syntax with its options) are available at the [voip-info page for Read](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Read).

Best!

EDIT: In the example, the digit read will be save in the dialplan variable **get**.

Comment: If you want to collect DTMF digits during playback of a file - and not after using the Read application - you can also use the Background application: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Application_BackGround

Comment: @MattJordan Isn't that designed specifically for reading (and jumping to) extensions instead of meaning-less digits? I chose Read for the answer because the OP did not specify the intention. Also, you cant specify a max number of digits, and you would need to have an extension per valid option, and an s as a catch-all, this seemed like too much for the question as it is

Comment: heh, good point.  I actually got Background mixed up with Read - thanks :-)

Comment: Actually I dont want to collect digits. I just want to stop the playing and go to next command

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Background command, which will get a single DTMF input from user.

To know about this command use this link
`http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+BackGround`

or type the below command in your server

```
asterisk -rx 'core show application Background'
```

Answer (score 0):

Then just collect a single digit, and do nothing with the collected variable :-)